# Blog page issue. The post title appear over the menu, and comments content too narrow to footer

Tags: wordpress

How can I fix this issue on WordPress static blog page?
Post title appear over the menu and comments contents narrow to footer.
Left some pics below:

`post title over menu`
[image: post title over menu]

`comments content narrow to footer`
[image: comments content narrow to footer]

Comment: Hello, i know you're new but how could you imagine that we can help you just with this ? Could you please give us some code ? Or at least your website URL ?

Comment: Website url  www.emmarachel.space. if you can go to blogs you can see. thanks.

Comment: I left some pics but I guess I cannot upload pics on here yet.